# Ethernet-Connection ubuntu with VMware Player

Tags: 14.04, internet, ethernet, vmware-player

I installed VMware Player 7.1.2 on my Windows 7. On my VM I installed ubuntu 14.04. Now I have problems connecting to internet. With my computer I am connected with ethernet. Ubuntu can connect with it but I am not able to connect to internet. Which settings do I have to change. There are a lot of settings (VMware Player Network Adapter, IPv4 Settings and and and...) and I am not a pro ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Without further data, the easiest fix is to go into the VM's settings directly, select the virtual network adapter, and edit it so that it is using NAT.

This will let it communicate outbound via the host computer's connections which are already active.  (This is also the least headachey to set up)

Comment: I tried it with NAT, Bridged, Host-only and Custom. I am not sure, if ubuntus connections settings are all right. Maybe the IPv4 Settings should not be Automatic (DHCP). But I have no clou, which addresses I could type in. I tried several ones.

Comment: Then the issue is a VMware one, and not an Ubuntu one, you should go to Super User and ask for help diagnosing VMware Virtual networking on a Windows 7 Host.  VMware Player works Out Of The Box typically, if it's not, it's not an Ubuntu problem, and a bigger one outside the scope of this site.